# Describe $\operatorname{Spec} R/fR$ with respect to prime decomposition of $f$ in a PID.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

This is an exercise from Goertz/Wedhorn: Let $R$ be a PID and $f\in R$ with prime-decomposition $f=\epsilon f_1^{n_1}\ldots f_k^{n_k}$. Analyse the affine scheme $X=\operatorname{Spec} R/fR$, so the topological space, stalks and $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for $U$ open.

What I have so far:$X=\operatorname{Spec} R/fR$ is homeomorphic to $V(f)\subseteq \operatorname{Spec} R$, and the prime ideals in the letter set are precisely $\{(f_1)=\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,(f_k)=\mathfrak{p}_k\}$. Thus, as a set we have $\operatorname{Spec} R/fR=\{\overline{\mathfrak{p}_1},\ldots,\overline{\mathfrak{p}_k}\}.$ For the stalk we have $$\mathcal{O}_{X,\overline{\mathfrak{p}_s}}=(R/fR)_{\overline{\mathfrak{p}_s}}\cong (R/(f_1^{n_1}))_{\overline{\mathfrak{p}_s}}\times\ldots\times (R/(f_k^{n_k}))_{\overline{\mathfrak{p}_s}}=(R/(f_s)^{n_s})_{\overline{\mathfrak{p}_s}},$$ because for $l\neq s$ we have $(f_l^{n_l})\cap(R\setminus\mathfrak{p}_s)\neq\emptyset$, as otherwise we would have $(f_l)^{n_l}\subseteq \mathfrak{p}_s$ and then also $(f_l)\subseteq\mathfrak{p}_s$ because the latter is prime. But this would force $l=s$ since both ideals are maximal. Now the topology on $\operatorname{Spec} R/fR$ is the discrete topology, because it's finite and the closed sets are precisely the finite subsets. Given an open - so arbitrary - $U=\{\overline{\mathfrak{p}_{m_1}},\ldots,\overline{\mathfrak{p}_{m_r}}\}\subseteq X,$ we consider $g=\prod _{i\neq m_j}f_i\in R$ and then have $D(\overline{g})=U$. This gives $$\mathcal{O}_X(U)=(R/fR)_{\overline{g}}\cong (R/f_1^{n_1})_{\overline{g}}\times\ldots\times (R/f_k^{n_k})_{\overline{g}}=\prod_j (R/f_{m_j}^{n_{m_j}})_{\overline{g}}.$$

My questions:

1. Is this correct?
2. Am I done with this exercise? I have kind of a bad feeling regarding if I'm done with such vaguely formulated exercises. I don't know if I could simplify a bit more, for example. Maybe a bit of life advice concerning this would also be appreciated. I'm grateful for any sort of help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scheme $X$ is the coproduct (=disjoint union) of the schemes $X_i=\operatorname{Spec}(R/\langle f_i^{n_i} \rangle)$, namely $ X=\coprod X_i$.
Each underlying topological space $\vert X_i\vert=\{p_i\}$ is a singleton set and $\vert X\vert=\coprod\vert X_i\vert=\{p_1,\cdots,p_k\}$ has the discrete topology.
The local rings of these schemes are $\mathcal O_{X,p_i}=\mathcal O_{X_i,p_i}=R/\langle f_i^{n_i} \rangle$.
Finally, for every subset $S\subset \{1,\cdots ,k\}$ and corresponding open subset $U=\{p_i\vert i\in S\}\subset X$ we have $$\mathcal O_X(U)=\prod_{i\in S}O_{X_i,p_i}=\prod_{i\in S}R/\langle f_i^{n_i} \rangle$$

**Note carefully:**
a) In general an affine scheme with finitely many points need not have discrete topology.
The simplest counterexample is $S=\operatorname {Spec A}=\{\mathfrak m, (0)\}$, the affine scheme associated to a discrete valuation ring $A$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.
The open subsets of  the topological space $\vert S\vert$ are  $\{(0)\}$,$S$ and $\emptyset$.
Thus $\vert S\vert$  is a non discrete space even though it has only two points: the closed point $\mathfrak m$ and the open but not closed point $(0)$.

b) However our $X$ **is** discrete because $X$ has dimension zero since  $R/\langle f\rangle$ is an Artin ring.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now that I think of it, all elements in the complement of $\mathfrak{p}_s$ go to units in $R/(f_s)^{n_s}$ anyway, so that localization doesn't anything and I end up with the same? And the same is true for $g$ in what I wrote?

Comment: Dear Const: you are welcome,  it was a pleasure to address  your question. Everything you write is correct but a little overwritten. The point is that if you have a local ring, say $R/(f_s)^{n_s}$, localizing at its maximal ideal doesn't change it $R/(f_s)^{n_s}=(R/(f_s)^{n_s})_{\overline{\mathfrak{p}_s}}$. So what I wrote is just a streamlined version of what you stated, which was essentially quite right.

Answer (score 1):

The "chinese remainder theorem" says the following: If $I_1,..,I_l$ are coprime ideals in a commutative ring $A$ ($I_i +I_j=(1)$ for $i \neq j$) let $I:=I_1\cdots I_l$.
It follows there is an isomorphism of rings

$$A/I \cong A/I_1\times \cdots \times A/I_l:=A_1\times \cdots \times A_l$$

If your ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$ are coprime you get such a decomposition. This gives a "decomposition"

$$Spec(A/I) \cong Spec(A_1)\cup \cdots \cup Spec(A_l)$$.

of $Spec(A/I)$ into a disjoint union of the schemes $Spec(A_i)$.

If your ring $R$ is  PID and your ideals $(f_i)\subseteq R$ are maximal, it follows your ideals are coprime, meaning  $(f_i)+(f_j)=(1)$ for $i \neq j$. Hence you get if $f:=f_1\cdots f_k$ an isomorphism of commutative rings

$$\phi: R/(f) \cong R/(f_1)\times \cdots \times R/(f_k) .$$

The map $\phi$ induce an isomorphism of schemes $Spec(R/(f)) \cong \cup_i Spec(R/(f_i)$
where the union is disjoint. The subscheme $X_i:=Spec(R/(f_i))$ is open and closed in $X:=Spec(R/(f))$. Since $(f_i)$ is a maximal ideal it follows $X_i$ is a reduced and irreducible scheme of dimension zero: $X_i\cong \{(0)\}$ where $(0)\subseteq R/(f_i)$ is the zero ideal. $X$ is a reduced scheme since it is a disjoint union of reduced schemes.

More generally: If $(f_i)+(f_j)=(1)$ for $i \neq j$ it follows $(f_i^{n_i})+(f_j^{n_j})=(1)$ and hence the ideals $(f_i^{n_i})$ are coprime for any $n_i\geq 1$. You get similarly using the crt an isomorphism of rings

$$R^*:=R/(f_1^{n_1}\cdots f_k^{n_k})\cong R/(f_1^{n_1})\times \cdots \times R/(f_k^{n_k}):=R_1\times \cdots \times R_k.$$

The ring $R_i$ is reduced iff $n_i=1$. Let  $X:=
Spec(R^*)$ and $X_i:=Spec(R_i)$. It follows $X\cong \cup X_i$ is a disjoint union and $X_i \subseteq X$ is open and closed. $X$ is reduced iff $n_i=1$ for all $i$.

Note that if $I,J \subseteq R$ are coprime ideals with $a\in I, b\in J$ with $a+b=1$ we get the following:

$$1=1^{k+l+1}=(a+b)^{k+l+1} =\sum_{u+v=k+l+1} \alpha_{u,v}a^ub^v$$

and for all $u,v$ it follows $\alpha_{u,v}a^ub^v \in I^k+J^l$ hence $1\in I^k+J^l$ and it follows $I^k$ and $J^l$ are coprime for any integers $k,l \geq 1$. Hence in your case if the ideals $(f_1),..,(f_k)$ are coprime it follows for any integers $n_i \geq 1$ the ideals $(f_i^{n_i})$ are coprime.

Your ring $R$ is zero dimensional and you will find a similar discussion here:

[Is the ring of the polynomials on a finite algebraic set always a product of local rings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913208/is-the-ring-of-the-polynomials-on-a-finite-algebraic-set-always-a-product-of-loc/3937070#3937070)

Comment: Thank you! I used the Chinese-Remainder Theorem in the two isomorphisms above. But since we are in a PID, all the ideals $(f_i)$ are maximal and $\operatorname{Spec}(R/f_i R)$ is a point, or am I mistaken? And then this decomposition is the fact that we have the discrete topology on $\operatorname{Spec}R/fR$?

Comment: Contrary to what you claim your morphism $\phi: R/(f) \cong R/(f_1)\times \cdots \times R/(f_k) $ is NOT an isomorphism unless $e_i=1$ for all $i$. Indeed if at least one of these $e_i$'s is $\neq 1$ the ring on the left has non zero nilpotents and that on the right has none. Despite what you write it is **not** true that the scheme $X$ is reduced (unless all $e_i=1$).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg - I believe you misunderstood the post - I assumed initially that the integers $n_i=1$ for all $i$.

Comment: I misunderstood nothing: you have added the assumption $n_i=1$ 11 hours ago, **after**  I pointed out your mistake yesterday. So the claim in your comment that you had assumed **initially** that $n_i=1$ is demonstrably not true since your edits are time stamped and can be checked by anybody.

Comment: The claims in your answer that $\phi: R/(f) \cong R/(f_1)\times \cdots \times R/(f_k) $ is  an isomorphism of rings and that $Spec(R/(f)) \cong \cup_i Spec(R/(f_i)$ is an isomorphism of schemes are also false (unless all $n_i=1$).[March 29, 8:20 UTC+2]

Comment: @Const - I added some details to make the answer more clear. Now you have two answers!

Comment: @hm2020 Thanks for your answer, and GeorgesElencwajg Thanks for pointing out the errors, both of which is valuable to me.

Comment: @Const - in the link you will find a discussion of the PID $k[x]$ where $k$ is a field. This is good for "intuition".