# Local ring of affine scheme finite over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have a question on Gortz/Wedhorn Algebraic Geometry, p.327 (12.5.1).

First let's see the next image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltebn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujOm5.png)

Let $k$ be a field and $X=SpecA$ be a finite $k$-scheme. Then X satisfies  the equivalent properties of Proposition 5.20 (image) and we have

$$ A = \prod_{x\in X} \mathcal{O}_{X,x},$$

where $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a local finite-dimensional k-algebra.

But I do not understand why $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is finite dimensional k-algebra. By the finiteness, $A$ is finite $k$-algebra. And $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} = A_{\mathfrak{p}_{x}}$ .
And by the Proposition 5.20, dim $A_{\mathfrak{p}_{x}}$ $\le$ dim $A$ $=0$.

So furthurmore every point of $X$ is closed (so maximal ideal in $A$) so the residue field $k(x)$ is finite extension of k ( $\because$ $X$  is $k$-scheme locally of finite type).
So if we can view $A_{\mathfrak{p}_{x}}$ as a $k$-submodule of $k(x)$, then $A_{\mathfrak{p}_{x}}$ is also finite dimensional over $k$. Is that true?

Anyway, can we deduce from this data that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is finite dimensional? Localization of  finite k-algebra $A$ at prime ideal(or maximal ideal) is also finite $k$-algebra?

Comment: I attempted to make some improvements to your post with regards to MathJax and grammar, but your recent edit overwrote them. Please do take a look - there are several things in there I think would help your post. Next, [images of text are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/) - please consider transcribing your images to MathJax. Finally, here is a hint: if $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a collection of vector spaces over a fixed field and $\prod_{i\in I} V_i$ is finite-dimensional, what can you say about the dimensions of the $V_i$?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But how can I embed my image in Question? I'm beginner. My reputation point is lower than 10 and it seems to difficult to do that. You mean, transformation of linked image to Latex looks form?

Comment: That is just part (ii) of Prop 5.20: $\Gamma(X, \mathcal O_X) = \prod_x \mathcal O_{X,x}$ is *finite dimensional* as a $k$-vector space. Or do you not understand the proof of 5.20?

Comment: Yes! I somewhat understand. Since $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}) = \prod_{x} \mathcal{O}_{X,x} $ is finite dimensional, by the dimension formula for product of vector spaces, each $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ are necessary finite dimensional. (true?) Thanks for comment!

Comment: @Plantation: You may find a similar question with answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913208/is-the-ring-of-the-polynomials-on-a-finite-algebraic-set-always-a-product-of-loc/3937070#3937070

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "But I do not understand why $O_{X,x}$ is finite dimensional $k$-algebra."

**Answer:** since $dim_k(A)<\infty$ it follows there is by the chinese remainder lemma a direct sum decomposition

$$A \cong A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_d$$

with $(A_i, \mathfrak{n}_i)$ an Artinian local ring for all $i$. There is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_i\subseteq A$ with

$$A_{\mathfrak{m}_i} \cong (A_i)_{\mathfrak{n}_i} \cong A_i$$

since $A_i$ is a local ring. Hence

$$A_{\mathfrak{n}_i} \cong A_i$$

is finite dimensional over $k$.

You find more details here:

[Is the ring of the polynomials on a finite algebraic set always a product of local rings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3913208/is-the-ring-of-the-polynomials-on-a-finite-algebraic-set-always-a-product-of-loc/3937070#3937070)